# How to actually upload a file using Flask WTF FileField

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-wtforms

In my forms.py file I have I have

```
    class myForm(Form):
       fileName = FileField()
```

In my views.py file I have

```
    form = myForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        fileName = secure_filename(form.fileName.file.filename)
```

In my .html file I have

```
     {% block content %}
     <form action="" method="post" name="simple" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>
           Upload a file
             {{form.fileName()}}
         </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
     </form>
     {% endblock %}
```

and it seems to work when I hit submit but the file is not in any of the project directories.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just had to call .save on form.fileName.file.save

```
    myFile = secure_filename(form.fileName.file.filename)
    form.fileName.file.save(PATH+myFile)
```

Answer (score 31):

Have you looked at this:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/#uploading-files

You have to set a few configs such as UPLOAD_FOLDER etc. You also have to call the save() function which I don't see in your posted code for views.py.

```
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to downvote, must have clicked accidentally and now I can't undownvote anymore!

Answer (score 13):

On form.fileName.file, call '.save'.

```
filename = secure_filename(form.fileName.file.filename)
file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
form.fileName.file.save(file_path)
```

Make sure to use secure_filename() to prevent users from putting in bad file names, such as "../../../../home/username/.bashrc".

Using os.path.join will generate the correct absolute path no matter what OS you are on.